# How to multline a boxed equation with words

Tags: boxes, multline

I want to use a box over a multiline equation with text in it

I used:

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{align*}
      \Aboxed{kT_0, kT_1, kT_2, \cdots, kT_n, \cdots 
       \text{is also an arithmetic sequence, where }kd
       \text{ is now the common difference.}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

but it makes the box extend past the right margin of the page. It won't wrap around even if I have a \begin{multiline} around it.

Comment: I don't really understand why you need the align* environment here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to wrap the “equation” in a minipage, so TeX can do line breaking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation*}
\boxed{
  \begin{minipage}{.75\displaywidth}
  $kT_0, kT_1, kT_2, \dots, kT_n, \dotsc$
  is also an arithmetic sequence, where $kd$
  is now the common difference.
  \end{minipage}
}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The value `0.75\displaywidth` should be adjusted to your liking.

*Don't* use `align` when there's a single equation to be displayed.